# Variational autoencoder for varying-length matrix-valued data

Tags: neural-networks, autoencoders, variational-bayes

I have a data set $\mathcal D \subset \mathcal X$ where each observation is itself a mini dataset, each with the same number of columns but differing numbers of rows, so $\mathcal D = \{X_1, \dots, X_n\}$ with $X_i \in \mathbb R^{n_i \times p}$. I want to be able to sample from a distribution over these matrices so I've decided to train a variational autoencoder, but I'm struggling with how to represent the data.

I first tried to define a fixed-dimension representation $\varphi :\mathcal X \to \mathbb R^d$ myself using domain knowledge, and then train the VAE on the $\varphi(X_i)$, but that's proven to be very hard and I want to try avoiding this. What architecture can I use to handle these directly? I've looked into things like RNNs but one aspect of this is that permuting the rows of the $X_i$ shouldn't change anything so I'm not sure how to encode that symmetry.

Comment: You could have a multi-level VAE, with two sets of latent variables. One for the individual observations within each $X_i$, and one shared between these observations. Then you'd need to define a way of retrieving the second set, but averaging across observations could work.

Comment: If $n$ is known, you could also use a Gaussian Mixture prior for the VAE

Comment: A Transformer without positional embeddings can produce fixed-length digests of arbitrary-length sequences, without considering position. (Positional embeddings were introduced to Transformers to mitigate the lack of positional information, but that 'bug' is actually a feature in your case.)